# How to get mouse buttons to work

Tags: mouse, button

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 x64 on my HP windows 7 computer.  After installation and login it brings me to the desk top. All I'm able to do is move my mouse pointer around. Clicking the left or right buttons do nothing at all. I have tried clicking on all the icons on the left menu & random spots on the desktop.

How can I get Ubuntu to play nice with my mice?

Mouse=  Logitech G5 & HP wireless
Intel Core 2 Q9300
8gb DDR3
Radeon HD 4650

Answer (score 6):

You probably have a driver problem, but in the chance that it's a config problem you can mess around with xinput.

First, open a Terminal. List your input devices:

```
# show all input devices
xinput list
```

You'll get something like this:

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Natural® Ergonomic Keyboard 4000        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Evoluent VerticalMouse 4                  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

I have an Evoluent VerticalMouse. You can see the identifier number is 12: "id=12".

I can test my mouse with:

```
# show all input from device with identifier number 12
xinput test 12
```

Now when I move my mouse or click, I get output in that terminal telling me what happened. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> to end the test.

You can reset your button map to the default with set-button-map. Note that I'm using my device name that was output by `xinput list`:

```
xinput set-button-map "Evoluent VerticalMouse 4" 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
```

Now try running `xinput test` with your id. If you're getting correct button responses here, then your xorg config was incorrect. (I don't know how to fix that yet -- I think you need to edit your xorg.conf to save the above settings. Looks like there's [more info here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Input).)